# Random order in wp_query with pagination

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

I have a shortcode that queries some custom posts and also has pagination added. Everything works, but I want to randomize the order. However when I set order to 'rand' in my args, every page in my pagination is totally random - meaning, the same post can show up multiple times on different pages. How can I randomize the order of all my posts but not on a per-page level? Here's my code:

```
function slaProductsArchive( $atts ){
    global $paged;
    $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
    $numposts = intval($atts['num']);
    $cat = $atts['cat'];
     $args = array(  
        'post_type' => 'product',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'posts_per_page' => $numposts, 
        'orderby' => 'rand',
        'product-category' => $cat,
        'paged' => $paged,
    );

    $loop = new WP_Query( $args ); 
    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); 

// Display my posts

    endwhile;
    $output .= '</div>';
    $output .= '<div class="slaPagination"><span class="prev-posts-links">' . get_previous_posts_link('<i class="fas fa-arrow-left"></i> Previous') . '</span> ';
    $output .= '<span class="next-posts-links">' . get_next_posts_link('Next <i class="fas fa-arrow-right"></i>', $loop->max_num_pages) . '</span></div>';
    
    wp_reset_postdata(); 
    return $output;
}
add_shortcode('slaProductsArchive', 'slaProductsArchive');
```

Comment: Keep in mind rand is not intend for archive.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few things you can do, based on *how* you'd like to handle it. A few ideas:

1. Seed the `random` order with something that changes
2. Store the order the "already shown" posts, and exclude them
3. Grab all the posts and shuffle them with a seed

There are other ways of course, and numbers 2 and 3 aren't particularly graceful outside of very specific uses. So let's focus on number 1, seeding the `random`.

The [`posts_orderby`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/posts_orderby/) filter is the one you're looking for. It allows you to, well… filter what the posts are ordered by.

```
add_filter( 'posts_orderby', 'so_69214414_edit_orderby' );
function so_69214414_edit_orderby( $orderby ){
    $seed = ''; // We need to figure out what to seed with
    return " RAND({$seed}) ";
}
```

Figured out what the define `$seed` as is really up to you, and how often you want the random order to change.

How it works is that if you `RAND(1)` - it will seed the random with 1, so as long as the posts are unchanged, they'll always be in that order. `RAND(2)` will produce an entirely different order than `RAND(1)` - but every time you use `RAND(2)` it's the same. For instance:

```
RAND(1) : [1, 3, 6, 2, 4, 5]
RAND(2) : [3, 5, 2, 1, 4, 6]
RAND(2) : [3, 5, 2, 1, 4, 6]
RAND(2) : [3, 5, 2, 1, 4, 6]
RAND(1) : [1, 3, 6, 2, 4, 5]
RAND(3) : [5, 1, 4, 3, 6, 2]
```

What I use for one of my WP sites is seed in the day: `$seed = date('M d, Y')`. That way, the posts always "randomize" at midnight every night, but page 1, page 2, page 3, etc will always be in order. For example:

```
Day 1: p1[1, 3] p2[6, 2] p3[5, 4]
Day 2: p1[3, 5] p2[4, 1] p3[2, 6]
```

If that doesn't work for your usecase, you can use [PHP sessions](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp) and store a random number in there, or you can store a random number in a cookie - and refresh that every time the user visits "page 1" so page 1 is always random, but page 2, 3, 4 always pull from that cookied-seed, etc.

Just figure out how often you want the seed to change, and then drop that in the `posts_orderby` filter, and you'll be good to go.

Just make sure that you use the `add_filter` *before* you call `new WP_Query()`, and then `remove_filter` afterwards if you don't want it to apply anywhere else!

Comment: This doesn't need to use a filter, since they are specifying their query parameters directly and make their own WP_Query, this is not using the main one. So `RAND(seedval)` can be put directly into the arguments array, https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/274163

Comment: Ah, thanks for the info! I guess I've got a few queries I can remove that filter from!

Answer (score 1):

For this, I used the WC-Session, since you're using products, I'm assuming you are using WooCommerce.  Each page stores in a session variable, so if you go back to a previous page, it's the same as before.  It also writes a separate array of posts that were done so you can use `post__not_in`.

So while this generates a random order, once a page is created, it's that order on refresh.

I also updated your usage of the `shortcode_atts` and made a condition in case there is no product category set.

```
function slaProductsArchive( $atts ){
    $atts = shortcode_atts(
        array(
            'num' => 10,
            'cat' => ''
            ),
        $atts, 'slaProductsArchive' );

    // Retrieve Previous WC Session Vars
    $done = WC()->session->get('viewed_randoms', array());
    $my_page = WC()->session->get('my_page', array());


    global $paged;
    $paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
    if (!array_key_exists($paged, $my_page)) {
        if ( !empty( $atts['cat'] ) ) {
            $args = array(
                'post_type'      => 'product',
                'post_status'    => 'publish',
                'posts_per_page' => absint( $atts['num'] ),
                'orderby'        => 'rand',
                'paged'          => $paged,
                'product_cat'    => $atts['cat'],
                'post__not_in'   => $done
            );
        } else {
            $args = array(
                'post_type'      => 'product',
                'post_status'    => 'publish',
                'posts_per_page' => absint( $atts['num'] ),
                'orderby'        => 'rand',
                'paged'          => $paged,
                'post__not_in'   => $done
            );
        }
    } else {
        $args = array(
            'post_type'      => 'product',
            'post_status'    => 'publish',
            'post__in' => $my_page[$paged]
        );
    }
    // Initialize $output ** This wasn't here before ** 
    $output = '<div>';
    // A variable to store the POST ID's of this loop
    $this_loop = array();
    
    $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
    
    // just to show something from the loop
    // You can remove this and put your own loop here 
    $output .= '<p>' . get_the_title() . ' ' . get_the_ID(). '</p>';

    // Set two array of the POST ID's
    $done[] = get_the_ID();
    $this_loop[] = get_the_ID();
    
    endwhile;
    $output .= '</div>';
    $output .= '<div class="slaPagination"><span class="prev-posts-links">' . get_previous_posts_link( '<i class="fas fa-arrow-left"></i> Previous' ) . '</span> ';
    $output .= '<span class="next-posts-links">' . get_next_posts_link( 'Next <i class="fas fa-arrow-right"></i>', $loop->max_num_pages ) . '</span></div>';

    // Set My Page Key =  Page Number - Value = each post ID
    $my_page[$paged] = $this_loop;
    // Store WC Session Var
    WC()->session->set('viewed_randoms', $done);
    WC()->session->set('my_page', $my_page);
    wp_reset_postdata();
    return $output;
}
add_shortcode( 'slaProductsArchive', 'slaProductsArchive' );
```

**Alternate Method Without WooCommerce**

In this method, I initialize a PHP Session, and use the cookie of the session ID to store a transient, since all of the rest is being done after headers are sent.  So the session is only for a session ID.  You could also simply set a cookie with whatever name you want and use it for a made up session, purely for using transients as this session.

```
function dd_register_session(){
    if(!session_id() && !headers_sent()) {
        session_start();
        session_write_close();
    }
}
add_action('init','dd_register_session', 1);

add_action('wp_logout', 'end_session');
add_action('wp_login', 'end_session');
add_action('end_session_action', 'end_session');

function end_session() {
    session_destroy ();
}

function slaProductsArchive( $atts ){
    $atts = shortcode_atts(
        array(
            'num' => 10,
            'cat' => ''
        ),
        $atts, 'slaProductsArchive' );

    // Retrieve Previous Session Data
    $done = $my_page = array();
    if (isset($_COOKIE['PHPSESSID'])) {
        if ( false !== ( $session_data = get_transient( $_COOKIE['PHPSESSID'] ) ) ) {
            $done = $session_data['done'];
            $my_page = $session_data['my_page'];
        }
    }
    global $paged;
    $paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
    if (!array_key_exists($paged, $my_page)) {
        if ( !empty( $atts['cat'] ) ) {
            $args = array(
                'post_type'      => 'product',
                'post_status'    => 'publish',
                'posts_per_page' => absint( $atts['num'] ),
                'orderby'        => 'rand',
                'paged'          => $paged,
                'product_cat'    => $atts['cat'],
                'post__not_in'   => $done
            );
        } else {
            $args = array(
                'post_type'      => 'product',
                'post_status'    => 'publish',
                'posts_per_page' => absint( $atts['num'] ),
                'orderby'        => 'rand',
                'paged'          => $paged,
                'post__not_in'   => $done
            );
        }
    } else {
        $args = array(
            'post_type'   => 'product',
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'post__in'    => $my_page[$paged],
            'orderby'     => 'post__in'
        );
    }
    // Initialize $output ** This wasn't here before **
    $output = '<div>';
    // A variable to store the POST ID's of this loop
    $this_loop = array();

    $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();

        // just to show something from the loop
        // You can remove this and put your own loop here
        $output .= '<p>' . get_the_title() . ' ' . get_the_ID(). '</p>';

        // Set two array of the POST ID's
        $done[] = get_the_ID();
        $this_loop[] = get_the_ID();

    endwhile;
    $output .= '</div>';
    $output .= '<div class="slaPagination"><span class="prev-posts-links">' . get_previous_posts_link( '<i class="fas fa-arrow-left"></i> Previous' ) . '</span> ';
    $output .= '<span class="next-posts-links">' . get_next_posts_link( 'Next <i class="fas fa-arrow-right"></i>', $loop->max_num_pages ) . '</span></div>';

    // Set My Page Key =  Page Number - Value = each post ID
    $my_page[$paged] = $this_loop;
    if (isset($_COOKIE['PHPSESSID'])) {
        set_transient( $_COOKIE['PHPSESSID'] , array('done' => $done, 'my_page' => $my_page), 10 * MINUTE_IN_SECONDS );
    }
    wp_reset_postdata();
    return $output;
}
add_shortcode( 'slaProductsArchive', 'slaProductsArchive' );
```

Comment: Hey Howard, thanks for the reply - unfortunately I'm not using WC. They are just cpt's with type of product.

Comment: I've updated the answer to use php session ID as a cookie, and WP Transients for storing the output order.